# How can I get elements under #document in html?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a problem with location of elements, which is under #document in Html. I need to type the card number in this element:

[id="encryptedCardNumber"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPCwY.png)

The id of the card is under a #document. Is there any way how to get this element and type the number in Cypress?

Thank you

Comment: It's in an Iframe, you can't get the element, change it of do anything with it (Assuming that it's not on your domain)

Comment: I don't believe that's true. They should be able to run commands and assertions inside of an iframe regardless of its origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some third-party Cypress custom commands that'll make it easy to execute commands and assertions within an iFrame. Cypress documentation suggests [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe).

Using the cypress-iframe package, you can achieve this doing something like the following:

```
cy.enter('.js-iframe').then(getBody => {
  getBody().find('input#encryptedCardNumber').click();
})
```

Comment: Hi Trent, thank you for your time spending with the answer. It works :) You really save my day :) BR Michal